# Schema changes are getting timed out in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

I tried setting up a 2 node Cassandra setup and it's quite done. Nodes are seems connected as shown below :

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address     Load       Tokens       Owns    Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.0.7.80   3.74 MB    256          ?       087ef42d-15d6-4cbc-9530-5415521ae7dc  rack1
UN  10.0.7.240  493.75 KB  256          ?       34d9098a-3397-4024-8dce-836001a8c929  rack1

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless.
```

1) Every DDL type operation is getting timed out here :

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace1 WITH replication = {'class':'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 2};
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
```

or

```
cqlsh> drop keyspace keyspace2;
OperationTimedOut: errors={}, last_host=127.0.0.1
```

2) Although, Above operations got timeout, I can see those keyspace in after few moments but these doesn't get replicated to other wherever the replication_factor = 2. Not sure whether these time out errors are related with replication or not as I tried the same by stopping one out of 2 nodes but got same timeout error even after.

```
Configuration file is as mentioned below :
cluster_name: 'MarketplaceDB-Cluster'
num_tokens: 256

hinted_handoff_enabled: true

max_hint_window_in_ms: 10800000 # 3 hours

hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb: 1024

max_hints_delivery_threads: 2

batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb: 1024


authenticator: AllowAllAuthenticator

authorizer: AllowAllAuthorizer

role_manager: CassandraRoleManager

roles_validity_in_ms: 2000

permissions_validity_in_ms: 1000

partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner

data_file_directories:
    - /var/lib/cassandra/data

commitlog_directory: /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog

disk_failure_policy: stop

commit_failure_policy: stop

key_cache_size_in_mb:

# Default is 14400 or 4 hours.
key_cache_save_period: 14400

row_cache_size_in_mb: 0

row_cache_save_period: 0

counter_cache_size_in_mb:

counter_cache_save_period: 7200

commitlog_sync: periodic
commitlog_sync_period_in_ms: 10000

commitlog_segment_size_in_mb: 32

# any class that implements the SeedProvider interface and has a
# constructor that takes a Map<String, String> of parameters will do.
seed_provider:
    # Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points.
    # Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
    # the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
    # multiple nodes!
    - class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
      parameters:
          # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
          # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
          - seeds: "127.0.0.1"

# On the other hand, since writes are almost never IO bound, the ideal
# number of "concurrent_writes" is dependent on the number of cores in
# your system; (8 * number_of_cores) is a good rule of thumb.
concurrent_reads: 32
concurrent_writes: 32
concurrent_counter_writes: 32

memtable_allocation_type: heap_buffers

#memtable_flush_writers: 8

index_summary_capacity_in_mb:

index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes: 60

trickle_fsync: false
trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb: 10240

storage_port: 7000

ssl_storage_port: 7001

listen_address: 10.0.7.80

internode_authenticator: org.apache.cassandra.auth.AllowAllInternodeAuthenticator

start_native_transport: true
# port for the CQL native transport to listen for clients on
# For security reasons, you should not expose this port to the internet.  Firewall it if needed.
native_transport_port: 9042
# The maximum threads for handling requests when the native transport is used.
# This is similar to rpc_max_threads though the default differs slightly (and
# there is no native_transport_min_threads, idle threads will always be stopped
# after 30 seconds).
native_transport_max_threads: 128
#
# The maximum size of allowed frame. Frame (requests) larger than this will
# be rejected as invalid. The default is 256MB.
# native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb: 256

# The maximum number of concurrent client connections.
# The default is -1, which means unlimited.
# native_transport_max_concurrent_connections: -1

# The maximum number of concurrent client connections per source ip.
# The default is -1, which means unlimited.
# native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip: -1

# Whether to start the thrift rpc server.
start_rpc: true

# The address or interface to bind the Thrift RPC service and native transport
# server to.
#
# Set rpc_address OR rpc_interface, not both. Interfaces must correspond
# to a single address, IP aliasing is not supported.
#
# Leaving rpc_address blank has the same effect as on listen_address
# (i.e. it will be based on the configured hostname of the node).
#
# Note that unlike listen_address, you can specify 0.0.0.0, but you must also
# set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0.
#
# For security reasons, you should not expose this port to the internet.  Firewall it if needed.
#
# If you choose to specify the interface by name and the interface has an ipv4 and an ipv6 address
# you can specify which should be chosen using rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6. If false the first ipv4
# address will be used. If true the first ipv6 address will be used. Defaults to false preferring
# ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
rpc_address: localhost
# rpc_interface: eth1
# rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6: false

# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160

# RPC address to broadcast to drivers and other Cassandra nodes. This cannot
# be set to 0.0.0.0. If left blank, this will be set to the value of
# rpc_address. If rpc_address is set to 0.0.0.0, broadcast_rpc_address must
# be set.
# broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4

# enable or disable keepalive on rpc/native connections
rpc_keepalive: true

# Cassandra provides two out-of-the-box options for the RPC Server:
#
# sync  -> One thread per thrift connection. For a very large number of clients, memory
#          will be your limiting factor. On a 64 bit JVM, 180KB is the minimum stack size
#          per thread, and that will correspond to your use of virtual memory (but physical memory
#          may be limited depending on use of stack space).
#
# hsha  -> Stands for "half synchronous, half asynchronous." All thrift clients are handled
#          asynchronously using a small number of threads that does not vary with the amount
#          of thrift clients (and thus scales well to many clients). The rpc requests are still
#          synchronous (one thread per active request). If hsha is selected then it is essential
#          that rpc_max_threads is changed from the default value of unlimited.
#
# The default is sync because on Windows hsha is about 30% slower.  On Linux,
# sync/hsha performance is about the same, with hsha of course using less memory.
#
# Alternatively,  can provide your own RPC server by providing the fully-qualified class name
# of an o.a.c.t.TServerFactory that can create an instance of it.
rpc_server_type: sync

# Uncomment rpc_min|max_thread to set request pool size limits.
#
# Regardless of your choice of RPC server (see above), the number of maximum requests in the
# RPC thread pool dictates how many concurrent requests are possible (but if you are using the sync
# RPC server, it also dictates the number of clients that can be connected at all).
#
# The default is unlimited and thus provides no protection against clients overwhelming the server. You are
# encouraged to set a maximum that makes sense for you in production, but do keep in mind that
# rpc_max_threads represents the maximum number of client requests this server may execute concurrently.
#
# rpc_min_threads: 16
# rpc_max_threads: 2048

# uncomment to set socket buffer sizes on rpc connections
# rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes:
# rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes:

# Uncomment to set socket buffer size for internode communication
# Note that when setting this, the buffer size is limited by net.core.wmem_max
# and when not setting it it is defined by net.ipv4.tcp_wmem
# See:
# /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max
# /proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max
# /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
# /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem
# and: man tcp
# internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes:
# internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes:

# Frame size for thrift (maximum message length).
thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb: 15

# Set to true to have Cassandra create a hard link to each sstable
# flushed or streamed locally in a backups/ subdirectory of the
# keyspace data.  Removing these links is the operator's
# responsibility.
incremental_backups: false

# Whether or not to take a snapshot before each compaction.  Be
# careful using this option, since Cassandra won't clean up the
# snapshots for you.  Mostly useful if you're paranoid when there
# is a data format change.
snapshot_before_compaction: false

# Whether or not a snapshot is taken of the data before keyspace truncation
# or dropping of column families. The STRONGLY advised default of true
# should be used to provide data safety. If you set this flag to false, you will
# lose data on truncation or drop.
auto_snapshot: true

# When executing a scan, within or across a partition, we need to keep the
# tombstones seen in memory so we can return them to the coordinator, which
# will use them to make sure other replicas also know about the deleted rows.
# With workloads that generate a lot of tombstones, this can cause performance
# problems and even exaust the server heap.
# (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets)
# Adjust the thresholds here if you understand the dangers and want to
# scan more tombstones anyway.  These thresholds may also be adjusted at runtime
# using the StorageService mbean.
tombstone_warn_threshold: 1000
tombstone_failure_threshold: 100000

# Granularity of the collation index of rows within a partition.
# Increase if your rows are large, or if you have a very large
# number of rows per partition.  The competing goals are these:
#   1) a smaller granularity means more index entries are generated
#      and looking up rows withing the partition by collation column
#      is faster
#   2) but, Cassandra will keep the collation index in memory for hot
#      rows (as part of the key cache), so a larger granularity means
#      you can cache more hot rows
column_index_size_in_kb: 64

# Log WARN on any batch size exceeding this value. 5kb per batch by default.
# Caution should be taken on increasing the size of this threshold as it can lead to node instability.
batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb: 5

# Fail any batch exceeding this value. 50kb (10x warn threshold) by default.
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50

# Number of simultaneous compactions to allow, NOT including
# validation "compactions" for anti-entropy repair.  Simultaneous
# compactions can help preserve read performance in a mixed read/write
# workload, by mitigating the tendency of small sstables to accumulate
# during a single long running compactions. The default is usually
# fine and if you experience problems with compaction running too
# slowly or too fast, you should look at
# compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec first.
#
# concurrent_compactors defaults to the smaller of (number of disks,
# number of cores), with a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 8.
#
# If your data directories are backed by SSD, you should increase this
# to the number of cores.
#concurrent_compactors: 2

# Throttles compaction to the given total throughput across the entire
# system. The faster you insert data, the faster you need to compact in
# order to keep the sstable count down, but in general, setting this to
# 16 to 32 times the rate you are inserting data is more than sufficient.
# Setting this to 0 disables throttling. Note that this account for all types
# of compaction, including validation compaction.
compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 16

# Log a warning when compacting partitions larger than this value
compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb: 100

# When compacting, the replacement sstable(s) can be opened before they
# are completely written, and used in place of the prior sstables for
# any range that has been written. This helps to smoothly transfer reads
# between the sstables, reducing page cache churn and keeping hot rows hot
sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb: 50

# Throttles all outbound streaming file transfers on this node to the
# given total throughput in Mbps. This is necessary because Cassandra does
# mostly sequential IO when streaming data during bootstrap or repair, which
# can lead to saturating the network connection and degrading rpc performance.
# When unset, the default is 200 Mbps or 25 MB/s.
# stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec: 200

# Throttles all streaming file transfer between the datacenters,
# this setting allows users to throttle inter dc stream throughput in addition
# to throttling all network stream traffic as configured with
# stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec
# inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec:

# How long the coordinator should wait for read operations to complete
read_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
# How long the coordinator should wait for seq or index scans to complete
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
# How long the coordinator should wait for writes to complete
write_request_timeout_in_ms: 2000
# How long the coordinator should wait for counter writes to complete
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
# How long a coordinator should continue to retry a CAS operation
# that contends with other proposals for the same row
cas_contention_timeout_in_ms: 1000
# How long the coordinator should wait for truncates to complete
# (This can be much longer, because unless auto_snapshot is disabled
# we need to flush first so we can snapshot before removing the data.)
truncate_request_timeout_in_ms: 60000
# The default timeout for other, miscellaneous operations
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000

# Enable operation timeout information exchange between nodes to accurately
# measure request timeouts.  If disabled, replicas will assume that requests
# were forwarded to them instantly by the coordinator, which means that
# under overload conditions we will waste that much extra time processing
# already-timed-out requests.
#
# Warning: before enabling this property make sure to ntp is installed
# and the times are synchronized between the nodes.
cross_node_timeout: false

# Enable socket timeout for streaming operation.
# When a timeout occurs during streaming, streaming is retried from the start
# of the current file. This _can_ involve re-streaming an important amount of
# data, so you should avoid setting the value too low.
# Default value is 0, which never timeout streams.
# streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms: 0

# phi value that must be reached for a host to be marked down.
# most users should never need to adjust this.
# phi_convict_threshold: 8

# endpoint_snitch -- Set this to a class that implements
# IEndpointSnitch.  The snitch has two functions:
# - it teaches Cassandra enough about your network topology to route
#   requests efficiently
# - it allows Cassandra to spread replicas around your cluster to avoid
#   correlated failures. It does this by grouping machines into
#   "datacenters" and "racks."  Cassandra will do its best not to have
#   more than one replica on the same "rack" (which may not actually
#   be a physical location)
#
# IF YOU CHANGE THE SNITCH AFTER DATA IS INSERTED INTO THE CLUSTER,
# YOU MUST RUN A FULL REPAIR, SINCE THE SNITCH AFFECTS WHERE REPLICAS
# ARE PLACED.
#
# Out of the box, Cassandra provides
#  - SimpleSnitch:
#    Treats Strategy order as proximity. This can improve cache
#    locality when disabling read repair.  Only appropriate for
#    single-datacenter deployments.
#  - GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
#    This should be your go-to snitch for production use.  The rack
#    and datacenter for the local node are defined in
#    cassandra-rackdc.properties and propagated to other nodes via
#    gossip.  If cassandra-topology.properties exists, it is used as a
#    fallback, allowing migration from the PropertyFileSnitch.
#  - PropertyFileSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by rack and data center, which are
#    explicitly configured in cassandra-topology.properties.
#  - Ec2Snitch:
#    Appropriate for EC2 deployments in a single Region. Loads Region
#    and Availability Zone information from the EC2 API. The Region is
#    treated as the datacenter, and the Availability Zone as the rack.
#    Only private IPs are used, so this will not work across multiple
#    Regions.
#  - Ec2MultiRegionSnitch:
#    Uses public IPs as broadcast_address to allow cross-region
#    connectivity.  (Thus, you should set seed addresses to the public
#    IP as well.) You will need to open the storage_port or
#    ssl_storage_port on the public IP firewall.  (For intra-Region
#    traffic, Cassandra will switch to the private IP after
#    establishing a connection.)
#  - RackInferringSnitch:
#    Proximity is determined by rack and data center, which are
#    assumed to correspond to the 3rd and 2nd octet of each node's IP
#    address, respectively.  Unless this happens to match your
#    deployment conventions, this is best used as an example of
#    writing a custom Snitch class and is provided in that spirit.
#
# You can use a custom Snitch by setting this to the full class name
# of the snitch, which will be assumed to be on your classpath.
endpoint_snitch: SimpleSnitch

# controls how often to perform the more expensive part of host score
# calculation
dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms: 100
# controls how often to reset all host scores, allowing a bad host to
# possibly recover
dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms: 600000
# if set greater than zero and read_repair_chance is < 1.0, this will allow
# 'pinning' of replicas to hosts in order to increase cache capacity.
# The badness threshold will control how much worse the pinned host has to be
# before the dynamic snitch will prefer other replicas over it.  This is
# expressed as a double which represents a percentage.  Thus, a value of
# 0.2 means Cassandra would continue to prefer the static snitch values
# until the pinned host was 20% worse than the fastest.
dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold: 0.1

# request_scheduler -- Set this to a class that implements
# RequestScheduler, which will schedule incoming client requests
# according to the specific policy. This is useful for multi-tenancy
# with a single Cassandra cluster.
# NOTE: This is specifically for requests from the client and does
# not affect inter node communication.
# org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler - No scheduling takes place
# org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.RoundRobinScheduler - Round robin of
# client requests to a node with a separate queue for each
# request_scheduler_id. The scheduler is further customized by
# request_scheduler_options as described below.
request_scheduler: org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler

# Scheduler Options vary based on the type of scheduler
# NoScheduler - Has no options
# RoundRobin
#  - throttle_limit -- The throttle_limit is the number of in-flight
#                      requests per client.  Requests beyond
#                      that limit are queued up until
#                      running requests can complete.
#                      The value of 80 here is twice the number of
#                      concurrent_reads + concurrent_writes.
#  - default_weight -- default_weight is optional and allows for
#                      overriding the default which is 1.
#  - weights -- Weights are optional and will default to 1 or the
#               overridden default_weight. The weight translates into how
#               many requests are handled during each turn of the
#               RoundRobin, based on the scheduler id.
#
# request_scheduler_options:
#    throttle_limit: 80
#    default_weight: 5
#    weights:
#      Keyspace1: 1
#      Keyspace2: 5

# request_scheduler_id -- An identifier based on which to perform
# the request scheduling. Currently the only valid option is keyspace.
# request_scheduler_id: keyspace

# Enable or disable inter-node encryption
# Default settings are TLS v1, RSA 1024-bit keys (it is imperative that
# users generate their own keys) TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA as the cipher
# suite for authentication, key exchange and encryption of the actual data transfers.
# Use the DHE/ECDHE ciphers if running in FIPS 140 compliant mode.
# NOTE: No custom encryption options are enabled at the moment
# The available internode options are : all, none, dc, rack
#
# If set to dc cassandra will encrypt the traffic between the DCs
# If set to rack cassandra will encrypt the traffic between the racks
#
# The passwords used in these options must match the passwords used when generating
# the keystore and truststore.  For instructions on generating these files, see:
# http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore
#
server_encryption_options:
    internode_encryption: none
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    truststore: conf/.truststore
    truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    #protocol: TLS
    #algorithm: SunX509
    #store_type: JKS
    #cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
    # require_client_auth: false

# enable or disable client/server encryption.
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: false
    keystore: conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    # require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    # truststore: conf/.truststore
    # truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]

# internode_compression controls whether traffic between nodes is
# compressed.
# can be:  all  - all traffic is compressed
#          dc   - traffic between different datacenters is compressed
#          none - nothing is compressed.
internode_compression: all

# Enable or disable tcp_nodelay for inter-dc communication.
# Disabling it will result in larger (but fewer) network packets being sent,
# reducing overhead from the TCP protocol itself, at the cost of increasing
# latency if you block for cross-datacenter responses.
inter_dc_tcp_nodelay: false

# TTL for different trace types used during logging of the repair process.
tracetype_query_ttl: 86400
tracetype_repair_ttl: 604800

# UDFs (user defined functions) are disabled by default.
# As of Cassandra 2.2, there is no security manager or anything else in place that
# prevents execution of evil code. CASSANDRA-9402 will fix this issue for Cassandra 3.0.
# This will inherently be backwards-incompatible with any 2.2 UDF that perform insecure
# operations such as opening a socket or writing to the filesystem.
enable_user_defined_functions: false

# The default Windows kernel timer and scheduling resolution is 15.6ms for power conservation.
# Lowering this value on Windows can provide much tighter latency and better throughput, however
# some virtualized environments may see a negative performance impact from changing this setting
# below their system default. The sysinternals 'clockres' tool can confirm your system's default
# setting.
windows_timer_interval: 1
```

Answer (score 5):

Schema operations in c* do not go through the regular write path in Cassandra. They are replicated internally via a separate mechanism.

If you check `nodetool describecluster` you will probably see that each of your nodes is on a different schema version. A rolling restart should fix this issue.

Answer (score -2):

start cqlsh with ip address of one machine .

like this :-

./cqlsh XXXX.XXXX.XXXX.XXXX

in distributed mode you can't start cqlsh as localhost . you have to provide ip address of that machine where you want to run cqlsh prompt  .

Answer (score -2):

Operation Time Out Error in `cqlsh` console of Cassandra. try to increase values in `cqlsh.py`.

```
cd /opt/apache-cassandra-3.7/bin
vi cqlsh.py
DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 600 and DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 600
```